# Where can I get a pre-paid SIM in Wellington, NZ and do I need ID?

Tags: cellphones, new-zealand, wellington

Arriving in Wellington, NZ in a few hours. Just need a cheap option for receiving calls and sending a few texts.

Are these available in 7/11, newsagents or such?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy option is [2degrees](http://www.2degreesmobile.co.nz/) (although there's also Telecom and Vodafone, if you're staying in cities, I'd recommend 2degrees).

There are many stores in Wellington that sell the sim cards, and last I checked ID was not required (I last bought a sim there 3 years ago).

They have a [handy store locator on their website](http://www.2degreesmobile.co.nz/storelocator) which shows dozens of locations in Wellington to buy - I usually just go to a newsagent or 'dairy' (like a corner store).  7/11s aren't in New Zealand, despite being common in Australia(!).

Comment: In March 2013 they did not require ID.

Comment: Thanks guys, my welcome to Wellington weather involved plane aborting landing due to wind extremities :P Holed up in Auckland for a cpl nights til next available flight, then will check it out or see if the store locator pops up anything near AKL airport.

Comment: In 2019 they still did not require ID.

Answer (score 3):

Would also go with 2 degrees if you want prepaid. You don't need to find a 2 degrees store; the sim cards are also sold at the (bigger) supermarkets like New World, Countdown and Warehouse.

In case you have a smartphone, you probably want to set up the data connection to check your emails or use google maps to find your way around:

http://www.2degreesmobile.co.nz/iphone

http://www.2degreesmobile.co.nz/android-settings

Not sure how much they charge pre megabyte on prepaid, but last time i checked it was still much cheaper to use your mobile phone plan than pay for wifi-access in most hotels/hostels. Some places charge you $10 for 100MB...